# Smart prettify html with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is there any way I can control the depth of unwrapping? My HTML's sometimes contain css. And prettify adds newline to every tag...

```
<html><body><h1>hello world</h1></body></html>
```

to:

```
<html>
 <body><h1>hello world</h1></body>
</html>
```

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

INPUT_FILE = "html_unformatted.txt"
OUTPUT_FILE = "index.html"

unicode_data = open(INPUT_FILE, "r", encoding='unicode_escape').read()
data = unicode_data.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features="html.parser")
pretty_html = soup.prettify()

with open(OUTPUT_FILE, "w") as f:
    f.write(pretty_html)
    print(f"Wrote to {OUTPUT_FILE}")
```

I have:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <h1>
   hello world
  </h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, according to beautifulsoup [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing), customising the `prettify` function is not an option. However, one could wrap `soup.prettify` into another function and replace the "pretty" text with one-line text.

That's what `prettify_except` below does, i.e. prettifying anything but the text contained in `tag_name`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = "<html><body><h1>hello world</h1></body></html>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

print(soup.prettify())

def prettify_except(soup_obj: BeautifulSoup, tag_name: str) -> str:
    regex_string = "<{0}>.*<\/{0}>".format(tag_name)
    regex = re.compile(regex_string, re.DOTALL)
    replacing_txt = str(getattr(soup_obj, tag_name))
    return re.sub(regex, replacing_txt, soup_obj.prettify())

print(prettify_except(soup, 'body'))

# original prettified

# <html>
#  <body>
#   <h1>
#    hello world
#   </h1>
#  </body>
# </html>


# prettified, except body

# <html>
#  <body><h1>hello world</h1></body>
# </html>
```